# Solr 6.2 boolean dynamic fields (_b suffix) are always setting to false even if explicitly setting a field to true

Tags: solr

I am facing this issue with Solr (version 6.2). The default schema has defined some dynamic fields:

```
        <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_is" type="ints"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true" />
        <dynamicField name="*_ss" type="strings"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_ls" type="longs"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_t"   type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_txt" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_bs" type="booleans" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_fs" type="floats"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_ds" type="doubles" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
```

But when a post a document like the following:

```
[{
 id:7,
 isActive_b:true,
 isReachable_b: 1,
 isWorthty_b:"True" 
}]
```

or (in XML):

```
<add>
 <doc>
  <field name="id">7</field>
  <field name="isActive_b">true</field>
  <field name="isReachable_b">1</field>
  <field name="isWorthty_b">"True"</field>
 </doc>
</add>
```

Using all the values that were supposed to be considered TRUE to Solr.

```
"BoolField: Contains either true or false. Values of "1", "t", or "T" in the first
character are interpreted as true. Any other values in the first character
are interpreted as false." (Solr Ref Guide 6.2)
```

The result is the following: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8M6Jh.png)

```
"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":12.316666,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"7",
        "isActive_b":false,
        "isReachable_b":false,
        "isWorthty_b":false,
        "_version_":1546068272520101888}]
  }}
```

or (in XML):

```
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0" maxScore="12.316666">
  <doc>
    <str name="id">7</str>
    <bool name="isActive_b">false</bool>
    <bool name="isReachable_b">false</bool>
    <bool name="isWorthty_b">false</bool>
    <long name="_version_">1546068272520101888</long></doc>
</result>
```

Anyone with the same problem or with a solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the same issue. Always to false on 6.2, working ok on 5.5.
The strange thing is that using the Solr Web UI booleans are correctly set.

Debugging we placed a breakpoint right after the query, when SolrDocument are returned, and booleans were already wrong.

We are rolling back to 5.5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You went even further to debugging it!! I think I will open an issue for Solr developers then!
Otherwise the way is to roll back to 5.5 as you said...

Comment: They answered my issue her https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9553. Seems like the problem is fixed on version 6.2.1, but i didnt test it yet!